# Training ideas for goalkeeper/wicketkeeper

Tags: football, cricket, training, coaching

I am a goalkeeper and a wicket keeper, and because these are specialist positions they need different drills and equipment to, say, midfielders or bowlers. I have my own drills but I'd like some new ideas and equipment.

So any recommendations? Either

> 1. Solo training for wicketkeeper/goalkeeper drills or ideas
> 2. Duel training for wicketkeeper/goalkeeper drills or ideas
> 3. Recommended training equipment for goalkeeping/wicketkeeping

Thanks a lot

Comment: Voting to close as too broad: this is at least two separate questions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some good equipment for goalkeeping:

> Rebound net
> [image: rebound net]
>   
> Reflex football 
> [image: reflex ball]

And wicketkeeping equipment:

> Katchet Ramp
> [image: Katchet Ramp]
> Small rebound ball
> [image: rebound ball]